# Are picture environments not allowed in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax, images

In a WordPress blog [post](http://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/formula-de-herao-da-area-de-um-triangulo/) of mine I used the following LaTeX code:

```
$\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(8,6)\thicklines
\put(1,1){\line(3,4){3}}
\put(4,5){\line(3,-4){3}}
\put(1,1){\line(1,0){6}}
\put(2.3,3.2){\textit{b}}
\put(5.7,3.1){\textit{a}}
\put(3.8,0.5){\textit{c}}
\put(4,2.7){\textit{S}}
\put(0.6,0.5){\textit{A}}
\put(7.1,0.5){\textit{B}}
\put(3.8,5.3){\textit{C}}
\end{picture}$
```

to draw a triangle. I tried to do the same in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55440/find-the-perimeter-of-any-triangle-given-the-three-altitude-lengths/55470#55470) but it didn't parse.

**Question**: Is this feature not allowed/supported?

**Added**: From the  Willie Wong's comment to J. M.'s answer it seems this is due to the existing design of the system. Is that so?

Comment: By the way, which LaTeX plugin do you use in the Wordpress blog?

Comment: @VesaLinja-aho I write everything using `$latex code$`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not in this [list](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands), so I guess not.

Comment: MathJAX is for type setting mathematics. It only supports that subset of the LaTeX features. As an aside: WordPress doesn't use MathJAX. WordPress pipes the LaTeX code to a real processor (probably TeXLive), gets an image output, and pastes the image output into the post. Which adversely affects the print quality.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks! Where can I get a short description of MathJAX?

Comment: @Américo: is the official http://www.mathjax.org/ page good enough?

Comment: @Theo: Yes, it is. Thanks!